# 'data-renderif' in Batman.js

Tags: batman.js

What exactly does the `data-renderif` attribute do with Batman.js?

I initially thought that it would render the DOM node only if the attribute value would be true. But then there's `data-insertif` that does that as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-renderif` is only meant to defer evaluating the bindings of a node's children until the binding value is updated to true. You probably want to use it in conjunction with `data-insertif` or `data-removeif`.

The `dataChange` method for this binding can be viewed [here](https://github.com/batmanjs/batman/blob/master/src/view/bindings/deferred_render_binding.coffee#L12). This function basically just removes the `data-renderif` attribute and initializes the children node's bindings.